# Match a word in a list of words regex

Tags: regex

I want the user to only be able to enter the values in the following regex:

```
^[AB | BC | MB | NB | NL | NS | NT | NU | ON |QC | PE | SK | YT]{2}$
```

My problem is that words like : PP AA QQ are accepted.

I am not sure how i can prevent that ? Thank you.

Site i use to verify the expression : https://regex101.com/

Comment: Please read a regexp tutorial, particularly study the difference between `()` and `[]`.

Comment: And regex101.com display an explanation of the regexp on the right side. That should help you understand why this is wrong.

Comment: Use `\b` to match word boundaries, rather than putting spaces around the word, because space won't match if the word is at the beginning or end of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most RegExp flavors, square brackets `[]` denotate *character classes*; that is, a set of individual tokens that can be matched in a specific position.

Because `P` is included in this character class (along with a quantifier of `{2}`) `PP` is matched.

Instead, you seem to want a group with alternatives; for that, you'd use parenthesis `()` (while also eliminating the whitespace, something it doesn't appear was intentional on your part):

```
^(AB|BC|MB|NB|NL|NS|NT|NU|ON|QC|PE|SK|YT){2}$
```

[<sup>RegEx101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/nrai9C/1)

This matches things like `ABBC`, `ABAB`, `NLBC`, etc.